# How do I compare a string to a string in a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a string stored in `text`. I want to compare this string with a list of strings stored in a dataframe and check if the `text` contains words like car, plane, etc. For each keyword found, I want to add 1 value belonging to the correlated topic.

```
| topic      | keywords                                  |
|------------|-------------------------------------------|
| Vehicles   | [car, plane, motorcycle, bus]             |
| Electronic | [television, radio, computer, smartphone] |
| Fruits     | [apple, orange, grape]                    |
```

I have written the following code, but I don't really like it. And it doesn't work as intended.

```
def foo(text, df_lex):

    keyword = []
    score = []
    for lex_list in df_lex['keyword']:
        print(lex_list)
        val = 0
        for lex in lex_list:

            if lex in text:
                val =+ 1
        keyword.append(key)
        score.append(val)
    score_list = pd.DataFrame({
    'keyword':keyword,
    'score':score
    })
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently? I don't like having too many loopings in my program, as they don't seem to be very efficient. I will elaborate more if needed. Thank you.

EDIT: For example my text is like this. I made it simple, just so it's understandable.

I went to the showroom riding a `motorcycle` to buy a `car` today. Unluckily, when I checked my `smartphone`, I got a message to go home.

So, my expected output would be something like this.

```
| topic      | score |
|------------|-------|
| Vehicles   | 2     |
| Electronic | 1     |
| Fruits     | 0     |
```

EDIT2: I finally found my own solution with some help from @jezrael.

```
df['keywords'] = df['keywords'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ')

text = 'I went to the showroom riding a motorcycle to buy a car today. Unluckily, when I checked my smartphone, I got a message to go home.'

score_list = []
for lex in df['keywords']:
    val = 0
    for w in lex:
        if w in text:
            val +=1
    score_list.append(val)
df['score'] = score_list
print(df)
```

And it prints exactly what I need.

Comment: Your current code thinks `scare` matches `car`.  Do you want that behavior or not?  If not, do you want `cars` to match `car` (stemming) or is that not important?

Comment: @JohnZwinck no, I don't want that. I only want to match `car` with `car` not `cars`. My actual dataset isn't in English anyway. That kind of plural as in `cars` doesn't exist here.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you use pandas and just not vanilla python for something like this, there are good tools for these things in the standard library that easily can be used

Comment: @jezrael if what you mean by keywords like `nice car` and `car`, yes there is a possibility for both. What do you mean by `text` in expected output? My expected output would be the scores for the appearance of those words in the keyword. I hope that's clear enough?

Comment: @ahed87 I use pandas because I load the data from csv or txt as dataframe. Is that a bad idea? I am so used to using pandas to load data from documents like csv. What tools do you recommend?

Comment: @jezrael I added some edits, I hope that's clearer.

Comment: @jezrael That's not exactly working unluckily. I am still trying to find what's wrong.

Comment: @jezrael actually I don't think splitting text is a good idea here. Can't we use fuction like isin() for string?

Comment: @jezrael I am getting numbers that do not make sense using split. Also I added an example on my question above.

Comment: btw, how have you intended to do the count when one keyword appears multiple times? I suppose your `if w in text` will count existance and not actual occurence. Nothing wrong with using pandas, more my own personal leaning to avoid dependencies when it's easy to do with vanilla python. Makes the code live longer, and is easier for others to use.

Comment: @ahed87 yeah, I think as of right now I only need existence, not occurrence. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Extract words with `re.findall`, convert to lowercase and then to `set`s, last get length of matched sets in list comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'topic': ['Vehicles', 'Electronic', 'Fruits'], 'keywords': [['car', 'plane', 'motorcycle', 'bus'], ['television', 'radio', 'computer', 'smartphone'], ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']]})

text = 'I went to the showroom riding a motorcycle to buy a car today. Unluckily, when I checked my smartphone, I got a message to go home.'
```

---

```
import re
s = set(x.lower() for x in re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text))
print (s)
{'go', 'motorcycle', 'a', 'car', 'my', 'the', 'got', 
 'message', 'to', 'home', 'went', 'riding', 'checked', 
 'i', 'showroom', 'when', 'buy', 'smartphone', 'today', 'unluckily'}

df['score'] = [len(s & set(x)) for x in df['keywords']]
print (df)
        topic                                   keywords  score
0    Vehicles              [car, plane, motorcycle, bus]      2
1  Electronic  [television, radio, computer, smartphone]      1
2      Fruits                     [apple, orange, grape]      0
```

Alternative solution is count only `True` values in list comprehension:

```
df['score'] = [sum(z in text.split() for z in x) for x in df['keywords']]
```

Comment: thanks. But I don't know why when I run this code, I got 1 on Vehicles, 2 on Electronic, and 1 on Fruits.

Comment: @AnnaRG - Added sample dataFrame, can you check it? Because it is really weird - `Fruits are 1`

Comment: Yeah, I have run your code and get `Fruits` as 1, which doesn't make sense, because none of the keywords of `Fruits` is found on `text`.

Comment: If check `df['word'] = [(s & set(x)) for x in df['keywords']]` what get for `Fruits` ?

Comment: I got even weirder result. I got {a} for `Vehicles`, {a,i} for `Electronic`, and {a} for `Fruits`

Comment: @AnnaRG - Is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'keywords']))` list?

Comment: It says it's a string. I think I see the problem here. I want to extract it as a list, but pandas reads it as an `<str>`

Comment: @AnnaRG So use `df['keywords'] = df['keywords'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ')` or  `import ast` and `df['keywords'] = df['keywords'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work. It still prints weird results. But I came up with my own solution in my edit above. What do you think about it? Can it be more simplified? Thanks a lot for the help by the way.

Comment: @Anna RG So it is like `df['score'] = [sum(z in text for z in x) for x in df['keywords']]`

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 alternative ways only using vanilla python.
First the data of interest.

```
kwcsv = """topic, keywords
Vehicles, car, plane, motorcycle, bus
Electronic, television, radio, computer, smartphone
Fruits, apple, orange, grape
"""

test = 'I went to the showroom riding a motorcycle to buy a car today. Unluckily, when I checked my smartphone, I got a message to go home.'
testr = test
from io import StringIO
```

StringIO is only used to make runnable examples, it's symbolizing reading a file.
Then construct a `kwords` dictionary to use for counting.

```
import csv

kwords = dict()
#with open('your_file.csv') as mcsv:
mcsv = StringIO(kwcsv)
reader = csv.reader(mcsv, skipinitialspace=True)
next(reader, None) # skip header
for row in reader:
    kwords[row[0]] = tuple(row[1:])
```

Now we have what to count in a dictionary. First alternative is just doing a count in the text-strings.

```
for r in list('.,'): # remove chars that removes counts
    testr = testr.replace(r, '')

result = {k: sum((testr.count(w) for w in v)) for k, v in kwords.items()}
```

Or another version using regex for splitting strings and Counter.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

words = re.findall(r'\w+', StringIO(test).read().lower())
count = Counter(words)

result2 = {k: sum((count[w] for w in v)) for k, v in kwords.items()}
```

Not saying that anyone of these is better, just alternatives only using vanilla python. Personally I would use the `re/Counter` version.